# I am using java sdk version of 19 and gradle version 7.6 but my flutter projects gives as a mismatch in gradle error

Tags: java, flutter, sdk, build.gradle

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             26.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I need to clear this error